# Invoking ignore case in switch statements

Tags: java

In the below code containing the switch statements, is it possible to incorporate the equalsIgnoreCase method, i.e., user gets grade message whether or not a or A is entered, etc. etc.?

I managed to get the right result by using "convert user input to upper case" method, but I was curious whether the ignoreCase method can be used here. I tried to do it, but it does not seem to work in any way, possibly because ignoreCase is a Boolean which returns true/false result, not a message. I tried researching this, but all online results suggest using toUpperCase method, something I already tried and worked.

```
  Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.println("Please enter grade.");
  String gradeLetter = scan.next();
  String message = "A";
  switch (gradeLetter) {
  case "A":
      message = "Excellent!";
      break;
  case "B":
      message = "Good job.";
      break;
  case "C":
      message = "You passed.";
      break;
  case "D":
      message = "You can do better.";
      break;
  case "F":
      message = "You failed.";
      break;
      default: message = gradeLetter + " is invalid.";
  }

    System.out.println(message);
```

Answer (score 3):

You could `switch (gradeLetter.toUpperCase())` but this looks like a better use case for `Map<String, String>` to me. Something like

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("A", "Excellent!");
map.put("B", "Good job.");
map.put("C", "You passed");
map.put("D", "You can do better.");
map.put("F", "You failed.");

// ... No Loop?
System.out.println("Please enter grade.");
String gradeLetter = scan.next();

System.out.println(map.getOrDefault(gradeLetter.toUpperCase(), 
        String.format("%s is invalid.", gradeLetter)));
```

Comment: I might have gone with `Enum` myself, though this solution has the virtue of being data/properties driven in the future, if the need arises :)

Answer (score 2):

As you already mentioned, you can switch on `gradeLetter.toUpperCase()`.

You can also use fall-through, where multiple case labels jump to the same block of code:

```
switch (gradeLetter) {
  case "A":
  case "a":
      message = "Excellent!";
      break;
  case "B":
  case "b":
      message = "Good job.";
      break;
  /* etc */
```

Consider, for example, "a" and "A". There is no `break` statement after `case "A":`, so execution continues straight into the `case "a":` block.